# Mapbox-GL setStyle removes layers

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm building a mapping web application using Mapbox-GL.  It has a lot of cool features.  I've set up the buttons to switch base maps (ie. satellite, terrain, etc) following the example on the [Mapbox website](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/setstyle/).

The problem that I am having is that when I change the style it removes my polygons that are loaded as layers and reloads the map.  I load in polygons from a Mongo database as layers based on user queries.  I want to be able to change the base map and keep those layers.

Is there a way to change the style without reloading the map, or at least not droping the layers?

Here is my code for the switcher, its the same as the example but I added a condition for a custom style:

```
 var layerList = document.getElementById('menu');
    var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');

    function switchLayer(layer) {
        var layerId = layer.target.id;
        if (layerId === 'outdoors') {
            map.setStyle('/outdoors-v8.json');
        } else {
        map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId + '-v8');
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's an example demonstrating that: http://bl.ocks.org/tristen/0c0ed34e210a04e89984

Unlike a mapping library like Leaftlet, Mapbox GL JS doesn't have a concept of "basemap" vs "other layers." All layers are part of the same entity: the style. So you need to keep some state of the data layer around and call its source/addLayer on each change.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help @tristen.  I was hoping that you could just swap the basemap, but Mapbox-GL is a bit different.  I used your example for inspiration.  Basically I had to save my loaded data to a variable and reload it using the `map.on('style.load' ...` function.  It works pretty well.

Comment: Thank you @tristen for the example and explanation.

Comment: Thanks @tristen. Any tips on how to do this for vector tiles coming from a tiling server (e.g. localhost/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf)? geojson can be stored in a variable but if you have a lot of data and only want to show the current bounding box's vector tiles, I'm unsure how to persist the same data...

Comment: @jondelmil sounds like a different question? See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/third-party/ for adding third party vector data to a map. The only thing this example demonstrates is swapping the base layer using `setStyle`.

Comment: @paolov the token under `mapboxgl.accessToken` has been disposed. The example should work by copying the code and providing your own access token!

Comment: What's confusing is map.getSource(sourceId) still returns true after a style switch

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I am late, but just for the record:

- `style.load` is not part of the public API
- use `map.on('styledata')` to monitor the style change

Please reference:

- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6210
- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3970#issuecomment-275722197

Comment: this is the correct answer for anyone here in 2020.

Comment: However, 'styledata' will fire multiple times, while 'style.load' only fires once. Yes, it isn't desirable to use a non-public feature, but it works (for now) in cases where the desired behavior is a single firing.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers suggest that `map.on('styledata')` is the correct approach. But it [doesn't](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8691) fire reliably, and the related `isStyleLoaded` is inaccurate.

Looks like we're stuck using `style.load` for now.